# Google Analytics + EasyTracker for Android sends wrong URL sometimes

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using EasyTracker to track Activities.

I have a point in the app where 2 activities are started almost at the same time (TabActivity and the activity which is in the first tab). Both have to be tracked.

This works - almost. I activated debug mode of Google Analytics and sometimes I see in the console that it sends 2 GET requests with the same activity name (the hosted one), instead of 1 for the TabActivity and 1 for the hosted activity.

I downloaded the sources of EasyTracker in order to step through it. I added an output in the last line which is executed before calling Google Analytics code (which doesn't have sources):

GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl.java

```
@Override
public void trackPageView(String pageUrl) {
    Log.d("TEST", "TRACKING:" + pageUrl);
    tracker.trackPageView(pageUrl);
}
```

And here I see that it outputs the names correctly - once my TabActivity and the hosted activity. But a bit later, when the Google analytics dispatches:

```
04-25 23:50:05.287: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1194): Called dispatch
04-25 23:50:05.297: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1194): Scheduled next dispatch
04-25 23:50:05.297: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1194): Sending 2 hits to dispatcher
04-25 23:50:05.297: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(1194): dispatching hits in dry run mode
```

I see 2 GET requests (which I'm not posting) with the same activity name (the hosted one). The key of this parameter in GET is utmp.

Clarification - with hosted activity I mean the one which appears in the first tab of the TabActivity. Not sure about the "correct" name for it.

So what can be the reason of this? Maybe something goes wrong because these activites are launched almost at the same time? Maybe Google Analytics doesn't expect this because isn't usual workflow... or no idea.

I also don't know how to debug this farther. I can't see into Google Analytics and the last output I can get is correct.

Any ideas?.